# Display an internal link URL on a page/article with Pelican

Tags: pelican

The usual syntax to make links with Pelican is:

```
This is [a link]({filename}/foo.md)
```

That works just fine.

But I'm on a page where I'd like to actually **show** the URL of the link. That is, I want the generated HTML to be like this:

```
<p>Here is the link:</p>

<a href="https://example.com/foo.html">https://example.com/foo.html</a>
```

I tried writing the obvious:

```
[{filename}/foo.md]({filename}/foo.md)
```

But that got rendered as:

```
<a href="https://example.com/foo.html">{filename}/foo.md</a>
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the feature in question was designed to behave that way. If it were me, I would use:

```
[https://example.com/foo.html]({filename}/foo.md)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of, but I figured I'd ask anyway, in case there was something I had missed.

Comment: I've actually noticed that you are limited to ONE instance of an internal variable in form of `{{ my_variable }}` per content/markdown file; ONE.

So, if I had to reused it repeatedly, I would break it apart the HTML file.